# Kafka producer partial serialization

Tags: java, spring, serialization, apache-kafka, marshalling

I have this dto.

```
@Data
public class ProductDto implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String price;
    private String quantity;

}
```

I would like to write custom serializer, adding or removing some fields from sending. for example "title". Now i have this.

```
public class ProductKafkaSerializer implements Serializer<ProductDto> {
    private final Boolean isTitleEnabled;

    public ProductKafkaSerializer(@Value("${dto.product.fields.title.enabled}") Boolean isTitleEnabled) {
        this.isTitleEnabled = isTitleEnabled;
    }

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String s, ProductDto productDto) {

        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(productDto);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

it is possible?

I would like to do it the way im doing it using json serialization like this.

```
@JsonComponent
public class ProductSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ProductDto> {

    private final Boolean isTitleEnabled;

    public ProductSerializer(@Value("${dto.product.fields.title.enabled}") Boolean isTitleEnabled) {
        this.isTitleEnabled = isTitleEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ProductDto productDto, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("id", String.valueOf(productDto.getId()));
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", productDto.getName());

        if (isTitleEnabled)
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("title", productDto.getTitle());

        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("quantity", productDto.getQuantity());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("price", productDto.getPrice());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```